# Assign the texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

Hey I don't know why the material I made in the Nodes Panel doesn't show up in render view. Can somebody help me please?[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate [An old issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139611/materials-are-staying-the-same-as-another-object-even-if-changed)
Please add your file to your question have you applied it to the right object is it on the right side

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: I'm pretty sure now whre the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it. It has to be something that I can only affect the colour of this material, but nothing else like Noise Texture or RGB- Curves, anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your material textures don't have any co-ordinates to scale from.

Add a texture co-ordinate node and wire into the texture nodes.

[image]

Comment: It worked! Big thank you!

Comment: @aggrise, no problem.  Please mark as accepted answer so that others know that it is resolved.  Happy Blending.